# jQuery function evaluation timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a page that uses the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). I'm trying to make the following happen on my page:

- click on the date field -> calendar pops up (datepicker takes care of this)
- click on a calendar day -> ajax request fires off, does some server-side calculations (checking for scheduling conflicts and the like), and displays a warning if it's a busy day

It's not exactly a validation, as the intent is to display a warning but still allow the user to submit whatever day they want.

What I have so far fires off the ajax, but with the wrong date. I think it's grabbing the date at page-load rather than when a calendar-day is clicked, so I'm guessing `datepicker('getDate')` is being evaluated at load time. How can I construct this to evaluate dynamically? Here's the current version (in coffeescript):

```
jQuery ->
  $("#rescheduler").click ->
    $("td[data-handler='selectDay'] a").click ->
      id = getUrlVars()["booking_id"]
      newDate = new Date(datepicker.datepicker('getDate'))
      postData = {}
      postData['booking_id'] = id
      postData['date'] = newDate
      $.post '/path/to/check_stuff', postData, ((data) -> doStuff), "json"
```

or, if you prefer native javaScript:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $("#rescheduler").click(function() {
    return $("td[data-handler='selectDay'] a").click(function() {
      var id, newDate, postData;
      id = getUrlVars()["booking_id"];
      newDate = new Date(datepicker.datepicker('getDate'));
      postData = {};
      postData['booking_id'] = id;
      postData['date'] = newDate;
      return $.post('/path/to/check_stuff', postData, (function(data) {
        return doStuff;
      }), "json");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what is happening is the date picker sets the date as, say, March 2, 2014 but this is set as UTC time so the value is something like March 2, 2014 00:00:00. Then when you create the new date from the passed in values your timezone gets added to the mix, causing the date to appear to be off.

If this is so (try logging some of the values to see what, exactly, you are working with) then you need to modifying the date picker value to account for time zone.

Something like:

```
    localDate       = new Date(dateToFix); //dateToFix would be the value from the date picker
    localTime       = localDate.getTime();
    localOffset     = localDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    adjustedDate    = new Date(localTime + localOffset);
```